# vueJS how to import and load components dynamically as a list is rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a list being rendered.

```
<div v-for="msg in messages">
   <div v-if="msg.type==='component'">
      <component v-bind:is="getComponent(msg.component)" :data="msg.data" :text="msg.text"></component>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can get a computed property to import and load a component if I hard code the component name, but i am not able to pass a property into a computed property.

If I instead call a method, i get a never ending loop and the browser crashes.

```
   //This works as a computed property
   getComponent() { 
      return () => import(`@/components/data/finance/GRNISummary.vue`)
   },


   //This does not work as a computed property. Computed properties can not accept parameters
   getComponent(component) { 
      const componentsList = {
        jurisdictionEvidenceCount: '/chart/export_control/JurisdictionEvidenceCount.vue',
        grniSummary: '/data/finance/GRNISummary.vue'
      }
      return () => import(`@/components` + componentsList[component])
   },


   //This as a method crashes the browser with an infinite loop of component loads 
   getComponent(component) { 
      const componentsList = {
        jurisdictionEvidenceCount: '/chart/export_control/JurisdictionEvidenceCount.vue',
        grniSummary: '/data/finance/GRNISummary.vue'
      }
      return () => import(`@/components` + componentsList[component])
  },
```

Comment: @Bravo As I said in my question this causes an infinite loop of component imports that crashes the browser

Comment: sorry, I missed that sentence

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic imports use `Promise` internally](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports), whereas `computed` property takes a factory function — so, yes, as a function it *does* actually accept parameters. For this to work, though, you're gonna want to use `require` instead.

```js
computed: {
  getComponent() {
    const componentsList = {
      jurisdictionEvidenceCount: '/chart/export_control/JurisdictionEvidenceCount.vue',
      grniSummary: '/data/finance/GRNISummary.vue'
    }

    return component => require(`@/components` + componentsList[component]);
  }
}
```

BTW, if you included `vue` in the [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions), that actually allows you to drop the extension type while importing a component. (Vue CLI should do this for you by default). Or you could [confirm it](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config) by running:

```sh
vue inspect resolve.extensions
```

Here are my proposed changes anyway:

```js
computed: {
  getComponent() {
    // Perhaps move this somewhere else though
    const componentsList = {
      jurisdictionEvidenceCount: 'chart/export_control/JurisdictionEvidenceCount',
      grniSummary: 'data/finance/GRNISummary'
    }

    return componentName => require(`@/components/${componentsList[componentName]}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, That certainly gets me further in that components seem to get loaded, but because they are not listed in the "components" property I get the error you would expect. I did also try ```this.components[componentName] = importedComponent``` but I get a render error. I am starting to think this might not be possible. :-(

Comment: @PrestonDocks If you give us more context, we might be able to help you figure it out.